# How to design inter cell space in UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have to implement a collection view as per this design.

[image]

I need to add white spaces between the cells. This is can be done by setting the background color of UICollectionView as white and add appropriate cell spacing and line spacing. However, I need to keep the dark background of collection view so that it matches with top bar color while dragging it. What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Set an inset of the image within cell with white background?

Comment: Yeah, applying an inset can help, but in this case, we have no left inset for the first column and no right inset for the second column.

Comment: Then, maybe some sort of manual calculation (even / odd) is needed in `cellForItem` ?

Answer (score 0):

One solution for this is to embed your view in Navigation Controller and then specify the color of navigation bar like this:

```
navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.AnyColorYouWant()
```

Other way is to set background of cells to white and set constaints for children of your prototype cells to match the whatever margin you want.

Comment: Then create outlet for left and right constraint and then set them to 0 or your   margin

Comment: It requires the knowledge regarding the position of a cell. That means in "cellForItemAtIndexPath", I have to determine the position of the cell based on indexPath and then apply margin. Actually, I was avoiding layout related stuff in "cellForItemAtIndexPath" as my layout is being handled by a custom flow layout.